# How do I change the userID an automation routine (file import) runs under in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, automationstudio

How do I change the userID an automation routine (file import) runs under in Marketing Cloud?  Employee left and we need to update the automation to be a support user ID.

Answer (score 0):

That setting is in Automation Studio -> Activities -> Import File.  There's a notification email address in that definition.

[image]